# What's the meaning of "Madame Onassis got nothing on you" in Rod Steward's "You wear it well" song?

Tags: meaning

I'm hearing a *Rod Steward's* song. Among its lyrics :

> You made me feel a millionaire and you wear it well
> **Madame Onassis got nothing on you**

What is the meaning of that last sentence ?

- That Madame Onassis can't compare to her ?

Comment: Look up [**have (got) nothing on someone**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-nothing-on-sb-or-sth)

Comment: Some might say that Kennedy's widow Jacqueline was effectively a "trophy wife" for the Greek shipping magnate Aristotle Socrates Onassis, and that because of her sky-high international social status, she made him feel even more wealthy than he was already.